# App was created for an older version of android

Tags: android, build.gradle

I've update my app for being compatible with the latest android versions, but by uploading at the play store, it's not available for my Android 11 device. It displays the message:

> **"This app it's not available for your device cause it's been created for a older android version"**.

I've changed in my build.grade file the **compileSdkVersion, buildToolsVersion, minSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion** for this.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 32
    buildToolsVersion '32.0.0'
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    }
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "es.myapp"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 32
        versionCode 140
        versionName "1.32.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
        javaCompileOptions {
            annotationProcessorOptions {
                arguments = ["room.schemaLocation":
                                     "$projectDir/schemas".toString()]
            }
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }

        debug {
            resValue("string", "PORT_NUMBER", "8082")
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

}
```

I'm missing something?

Thx all!

Comment: I'm also facing the same behavior here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76016486/play-store-fails-to-detect-device-compatibility Did you find a solution in the meanwhile?

Comment: Hi! I've added a answer in your thread. Hope it helps you.